# Asset Creation - 9patch SplashScreen and ScreenDensity

Tags: android, size, photoshop, pixel

So I get the whole Android pixel independency thing.

I'm creating a SplashScreen that is using a 9patch that will stretch its edges to account for all screensizes.

I also use a differenlty sized 9patch image in `ldpi` `mpdi` `hdpi` `xhdpi` for each splash screen as well. 
That way the logo (the non stretched area of the 9patch) will be the correct size.

I know `mdpi` is 1.0 and `hdpi` x1.5 in relative size and `xhdpi` is x2, but **when I'm creating that first mdpi image how do I know how many pixels wide/high it should be**?

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really there's no one answer. Firstly though, I wouldn't start at mdpi and scale up -- It's best to start at the highest quality that you can. Vector, if it fits the design, or a high resolution image (even larger than the largest screen size you currently plan to support). Then, from there, just downsize for the device that you plan to test. For example, a typical HDPI resolution would be 480 x 800, so fit it appropriately there. An XHDPI resolution might be something like 1280 x 720. It's best to just leave a good amount of margin on the edges in case it's used on a device with a different aspect ratio, or something. But yeah, basically, design as large as you can, and then just export based on some average screen resolutions for the density bucket you're working on.

Answer (score 1):

> (...) when I'm creating that first mdpi image how do I know how many pixels
>   wide/high it should be?

Since `mdpi` is the baseline for all other density buckets, `1dp` on an `mdpi` device will translate to exactly `1px`. In other words, use an `mdpi` device to figure out the relative size on the screen and from there on apply the given scaling ratios to produce resources for the `ldpi`, `hdpi` and `xhdpi` buckets. Obviously you do not actually have to scale up that `mdpi` resource - all you need determine is the size for that screen density and then you can use whatever source file to produce images for all buckets.

The link xBroak has given, is actually the best source of information regarding your question. A quote from there to support above statements:

> **The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a
>   160 dpi screen**, which is the baseline density assumed by the system
>   for a "medium" density screen.

It may also come in handy to be aware of the simple `d(i)p` to `px` formula (also from that same link):

> The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: **`px = dp * (dpi
>   / 160)`**

With this information, you can easily verify that `1dp` on an `mdpi` device (with `160dpi` screen) is equal to `1px`. Just fill in `160dpi` and you get `px = dp * (160 / 160)`, which simplifies to `px = dp * 1`, and hence `px = dp` for `160dpi`. QED. :)

Comment: SO basically like @kcoppock is saying, you just pick a resolution and scale from that point of reference

Comment: @Blundell: Slightly more specific: determine the resolution on an `mdpi` device such that it visually matches what you're after, and then use that as point of reference for the other buckets.

Comment: So a MDPI device would would be what size 320px x 480px. Got it

Answer (score -1):

These are your basic guidelines:

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).
```

More info: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html